# Different depth of water can achieve different negative pressure, right?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

Different depth of water can achieve different negative pressure, right? Because there is only one atmospheric pressure on the water surface, it can only reach a negative atmospheric pressure, and the pressure at the bottom of the water is greater than one atmospheric pressure, so the pressure at the bottom of the water can reach a greater negative pressure. Am I right?

For example, if a closed vessel with an internal atmospheric pressure is placed at the bottom of the water, the pressure in the vessel will be lower than the water pressure. What is the vacuum in the container?

**I mean the degree of vacuum that can be achieved at the bottom of the water**

Comment: Are you saying that the pressure at the bottom of a swimming pool is lower than at the surface?

Comment: @ChetMiller I mean the degree of vacuum that can be achieved at the bottom of the water

Comment: Please show the equations for this.

Comment: @ChetMiller For example, if a closed vessel with an internal atmospheric pressure is placed at the bottom of the water, the pressure in the vessel will be lower than the water pressure. What is the vacuum in the container?

Comment: If you want to think of it that way, that’s fine.  But what’s the point?

Answer (score 1):

A submarine (or other closable vessel) on the surface has an internal pressure on 1 atm, 10m below the sea the water pressure adds another 1atm (approximately) outside the vessel, so the inside of the submarine is now -1 atm relative to the surrounding water.

The pressure gradient in the water depends on the density of the water and the local strength of gravity.  salt water is denser than fresh water, cold water is denser than warm water etc... 1 atm per 10m or 10Pa per 1mm  are approximate figures for this gradient.

9.8Pa per 1mm is about right for clean fresh water in standard gravity.

to an observer in the vessel or on the surface there is no vacuum pressure, but to an observer in the water there is a vacuum.

Comment: Is the container vacuum relative to water?

Answer (score 1):

> Different depth of water can achieve different negative pressure, right?...so the pressure at the bottom of the water can reach a greater negative pressure.

No pressure at the bottom of container is not just greater in magnitude but also in it's effect.

Let us first consider absolute pressure. It is a measure of how much the molecules in a given volume are bumping into one another and the surrounding objects. So $2Pa$ pressure means twice more bumping (momentum exchange) per given area as compared to $1Pa$.

Now if you consider the relative pressure between two point  then it's the difference between the pressure at one point from another. And surely it can be negative. How? Say if some point is at pressure $k$ and the given one is at $p$ then the relative pressure is $p-k$ which can be negative if $p \lt k$ which is a statement irrespective of sign hence it is satisfied even if $p \lt 0$. So if $p \lt 0$ then negative pressure is only possible if $k$ is less negative than $p$.

Now vacuum is a special condition in which there is absolute $0 Pa$ pressure or (approcmximately) $-1 \ atm$ with respect to the surface of water. Absolute vacuum isn't physically possible.